# Do *Ambystoma macrodactylum* predate on *ceuthophilinaens* like the one I observed?

Tags: zoology, entomology, food, ethology, predation

I observed this [*Ambystoma macrodactylum*](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/117621442) within half of a meter of this [*Ceuthophilinaen*](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/117621381) under an old board. I can imagine salamanders eating cricket-like things, but this question is far outside my expertise. [This page](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/26754-Ambystoma-macrodactylum) says that long-toed salamanders prey on small crustaceans, dipterans and tadpoles at the larval stage, but doesn't seem to discuss their terrestrial diet. Not much about predators on the putative prey's [page](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/340768-Ceuthophilinae).

Do *Ambystoma macrodactylum* predate on *ceuthophilinaens* like the one I observed?